# PHP Help: Add link to product > custom image flipper for Woo Product Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have the code below that changes Woo Commerce product archive/loop images to flip between 2 images on hover, instead of just the default single/static 'featured image' (second image is taken from product gallery images).

It is indeed flipping images as it should and working well.

Problem is that the images are no longer clickable - therefore they are not linking to the actual product as they should / did before.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

N

```
function tp_create_flipper_images() {
    global $post, $woocommerce ,$product;
    $get_gallery_image_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();
    //wp_dbug($get_gallery_image_ids);
    $get_image_id  = $product->get_image_id();
    $image_url_top = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'woocommerce_thumbnail');
    $placeholder_img = wc_placeholder_img_src('woocommerce_thumbnail');
    //wp_dbug($placeholder_img);
    if($get_image_id){

        $image_top_alt = get_post_meta($get_image_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
        if(!$image_top_alt){
            $image_top_alt = $product->get_name();
        }

        if($get_gallery_image_ids){

            $image_bottom_alt = get_post_meta($get_gallery_image_ids[0], '_wp_attachment_image_alt', TRUE);
            if(!$image_bottom_alt){
                $image_bottom_alt = $image_top_alt;
            }

            $output = '<div class="tp-image-wrapper">';
                //$post->post_title;
                //$image_url_top = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'woocommerce_thumbnail');
                $image_url_bottom = wp_get_attachment_image_src($get_gallery_image_ids[0], 'woocommerce_thumbnail' );
                $output .= '<img class="tp-image" src="'.$image_url_top.'" alt="'.$image_top_alt.'" />';
                //$output .= '<img class="bottom" width="300" height="300" src="'.$image_url_bottom[0].'" />';
                $output .= '<img class="tp-image-hover" src="'.$image_url_bottom[0].'" alt="'.$image_bottom_alt.'" />';
                        
            $output .= '</div>';
            
        }
        else{
            $output = '<div class="tp-image-wrapper"><img class="image" src="'.$image_url_top.'" alt="'.$image_top_alt.'" /></div>';
        }

    }
    else{
        $output = '<div class="tp-image-wrapper"><img class="image" src="'.$placeholder_img.'" /></div>';
    }

    echo $output;
}
```

}

Comment: Update:

I added / Edited below line, I can nopw get the images to be clickable to a link, but I don't know how to have the link call the relevant Product. Please Help!
///
$output .= '<a href="<?php echo get_permalink($product_id) ?>"><img class="tp-image-hover" src="'.$image_url_bottom[0].'" alt="'.$image_bottom_alt.'" /></a>'; ///

Comment: try get_permalink( $product->get_id() ); Since 3x version i think you cant access directly product ID . Also keep it consistant at some places you have $post->ID then $product ids.. just pick one and will be more clear for anyone looking your code later or even for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help and your advice Martin :)  See my answer for the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user @Bhauti, both his solutions below worked for me. Leaving it here incase anyone is searching for the same answer.

```
$output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'"><img class="tp-image-hover" src="'.$image_url_bottom[0].'" alt="'.$image_bottom_alt.'" /></a>';
```

OR

```
$output .= '<a href="'.get_permalink( $product->get_id() ).'"><img class="tp-image-hover" src="'.$image_url_bottom[0].'" alt="'.$image_bottom_alt.'" /></a>';
```